# How do I roller-skate?

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console, commodore-64, california-games

How do I get my roller-skater to skate?  I've tried forward, back, forward, back, but she just won't move!

I am playing this through the Wii's Virtual Console, which (oddly enough) uses the Commodore 64 version of California Games, rather than the NES version.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you had to alternate UP and Down in the right corners to move forward.

I had to confirm, so I got the instruction [on the c64-wiki](https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/California_Games#Skating) :

> ***Controls:***
>   - [image: Joy|Fire] Fire button: start
>   - [image: Joy|RightForwards] + [image: {Joy|RightBackwards] Joystick right up/right down in turns: speed up
>   - [image: Joy|LeftBackwards] Joystick left down: 360° turn clockwise
>   - [image: Joy|LeftForwards] Joystick left up: 360° turn anticlockwise
>   - [image: Joy|Fire] Press fire button: hunker down
>   - [image: Joy|Neutral] Let go fire button: jump